# How to block HTTP and allows only HTTPS for AWS API Gateway with custom domain name map

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I've added certificate with custom domain name map in AWS API gateway but it allows HTTP automatically, how can I block normal HTTP and only allows HTTPS?

Answer (score 4):

All API Gateway APIs are fronted with a CloudFront distribution. Each of these CloudFront distributions (whether it's a Custom Domain like yours or the default *.execute-api distribution) is configured to [redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html). Although CloudFront has the option to strictly require HTTPS and return 403 on HTTP requests we currently don't expose this option for simplicity.

If you feel you have valid use case for requiring HTTPS without a redirect please open a support ticket and the team can evaluate your request.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, so the redirect happen on behind and the tool automatically redirect to https without notice.

Comment: Are API gateways really always fronted with Cloudfont?  I just looked at one of my accounts that has just an apigw and a few lambdas and the account doesn't seem to have a cloudfront distribution.  Maybe adding cloudfront is common practice but it doesn't seem to be automatic.

Comment: that's true. I tried from curl and I got a 307 (temporary redirect)