# How do I redirect both HTTP and HTTPS to WWW without using htaccess?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, redirect, dns, serverless

I just published a Python / Flask serverless website (no `.htaccess`), and I am trying to redirect all **non-www to www**.

I use NameCheap as my DNS registrar, and AWS API Gateway to serve the website. My main record for the website is:

- CNAME: **www** -> `abc012def3456.cloudfront.net`

This CNAME works perfectly; I can access my website at `https://www.example.com` or `http://www.example.com` (which redirects to the https version).

To redirect the non-www to www, I added:

- URL Redirect Record (301): **@** -> `https://www.example.com`

The thing is,  `http://example.com` successfully redirects me to `https://www.example.com`, but `https://example.com` **does not**. Instead, it just does not respond.

What am I doing wrong? Are there any other recommended ways to redirect both `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`?

Comment: How was this “URL Redirect Record” added?

Comment: Added via the Namecheap dashboard. I've also experimented with a CNAME, but got similar results.

Comment: The _protocol_ should not affect the DNS/CNAME at all, as it’s an entirely unrelated layer, applied after the target host IP is resolved: no (HTTP) 301 here.. or is Namecheap an actual HTTP proxy? What handles the HTTP to HTTPS upgrade/redirection?

Comment: I did not find any information on Namecheap providing a proxy service. Their listed http -> https upgrade is only for their own hosted sites (and such is an expected feature hosts provide..). So then, we look to AWS.. what in the _AWS host / API Gateway_ is causing the HTTPS upgrade/redirect? Why is this not consistent?

Comment: The question of DNS/CNAME involvement can be answered and resolved with ping (noting IP), dig, nslookup or an online tool like https://network-tools.com/nslookup/ (etc) and then aside if www.foo.com and foo.com are resolving the same address(es). Using cURL (HTTP) might indicate what is wrong with the HTTPS connection itself or redirect/upgrades relating to such.

Comment: So including how/where the Python site is deployed, and it’s relationship to AWS is also relevant, and should be reflected in the question.. I’m ‘assuming’ it’s not on Namecheap, which leads to “where is that 301 rule, and what gives the expectation it is applied via (Namecheap) dashboard”?

Comment: I believe CloudFront is causing the HTTPS redirect (by default). "All API Gateway APIs are fronted with a CloudFront distribution". For the `www` version, the HTTPS redirect is working fine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200229/how-to-block-http-and-allows-only-https-for-aws-api-gateway-with-custom-domain-n

Comment: Using redirectcheck.com, I see that `http://example.com` successfully redirects: `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` and `X-Served-By: Namecheap URL Forward` `Location: https://www.example.com`. However, `https://example.com` results in itself, no redirects.

Comment: Cute “Namecheap URL Forward”, magic. Definitely something specific in it’s configuration.. check out the Namecheap help forums / documentation / customer service. This is an issue specific to some Namecheap services used (needed?), not DNS. It also appears to hav me nothing to do with AWS or Python. I might create a new question with refined context and information.

Comment: And, *why doesn’t the DNS point to AWS*? Or why is whatever that is called using some Namecheap proxy? It almost sounds like the issue is (unexpectedly) using some Namecheap hosting as the DNS target, instead of AWS? Or is mention of AWS unrelated to the issue? *Verify the resolved IPs*.

Comment: @user2864740 the namecheap proxy is doing the redirect.  OP apparently has it set up right, *and it is almost certainly working as expected*.  This is something of a joke of an adjunct service that some hosting providers still throw in... it was useful in the days before everyone realized that we should be using HTTPS everywhere.  It only supports HTTP.

Comment: Sounds like a time to add a Cheapname, https, and proxy tag while remove (most) everything else, updating content as relevant  .. *sigh*

Comment: I'm using Namecheap simply because it's free (as an alternative to Route 53). I am honestly not sure what to do at this point. The HTTPS root domain does not return anything. I even thought of just allowing both www and non-www, but then the @ CNAME conflicts with my MX record...

Comment: I think I got it! I followed a tutorial, that uses S3 and CloudFront, and created an ALIAS record `@ -> new.cloudfront.url`. I'm new to AWS so I'm not totally sure how it works, but it works! I might answer this SO question. 
https://www.nclouds.com/blog/configuring-cloudfront-to-use-acm-amazon-certificate-manager-and-redirect-all-the-traffic-to-https/

Comment: So, by _not_ using the Namecheap proxy? *rolls eyes* Anyway, hooray and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can use elastic loadbalancers in AWS to redirect traffic from http to https. Below is a link to the docs

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

The basics are:

1. Create an https listener that redirects traffic to your flask server(s) on the port they are listening to
2. Create an http listener that redirects traffic to your https listener.

Happy Encrypting!

Answer (score -1):

you can use python3-certbot to automate such stuffs
because certbot is an https installer or automatic https for the website/server manually
instead of editing it from a .htaccess file

[image]

https://pypi.org/project/certbot/